# Highchart heatmap unable to display array of data

Tags: highcharts

Not able to display data in heat map coming from JSON. Only X and Y axis are shown.

```
     var data1=[
["2016-01-01", 0, 20.0],
["2016-01-01", 1, 9.0],
["2016-01-01", 2, 10.0]

]
```

**[Fidlele link][1]**

http://jsfiddle.net/nxgzeo34/2/

Please advise

Comment: Datetime format should be in timestamp, not in string. Also, you do not need a canvas plugin for rendering. http://jsfiddle.net/11f05myu/

Comment: @morganfree i have more than 10k data. if want convert it time stamp need loop 10k data on client side. any best approach for this

Comment: You should do it on server side, or you can group your data on the server and send that grouped data to the client.